# Insert followed by delete query

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, sql-insert, sql-delete

I want to apply the delete query first on my table and then apply the insert query on the same table.

variable_page_category table has 2 columns (page_category_id, variable_id). It's a composite primary key.

My Table can be like this:

```
page_category_id  | 1  2  3  4  5
variable_id       | 1  1  1  2  2
```

```
result_variable_page_category_delete AS (
        DELETE FROM common.variable_page_category
        WHERE variable_id = (dynamic_variable_json->>'id')::BIGINT
        RETURNING 1
    ),
    result_variable_page_category AS (
        INSERT INTO common.variable_page_category (page_category_id, variable_id)
        SELECT
            (page_category_id::TEXT)::BIGINT,
            (dynamic_variable_json->>'id')::BIGINT
        FROM jsonb_array_elements_text((dynamic_variable_json->>'page_category_id')::JSONB) AS page_category_id
        RETURNING 1
    )
```

but this didn't perform sequentially and I'm getting this error. Both queries are individually correct.

`ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint \"variable_page_category_pkey\"\n  Detail: Key (page_category_id, variable_id)=(1, 1) already exists.`

How can I combine both the query so that delete query complete before insert?
Update query is also an option but because I'm new I can't handle update query with ease that's why trying this approach first.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply concatenate both queries using `;` ??

```sql
DELETE FROM common.variable_page_category
        WHERE variable_id = (dynamic_variable_json->>'id')::BIGINT
;
INSERT INTO common.variable_page_category (page_category_id, variable_id)
        SELECT
            (page_category_id::TEXT)::BIGINT,
            (dynamic_variable_json->>'id')::BIGINT
        FROM jsonb_array_elements_text((dynamic_variable_json->>'page_category_id')::JSONB) AS page_category_id
```

You might want to add a transaction depending on your client configuration

Comment: I already tried this. This didn't work. I got the error while executing.

Comment: have you tried with a transaction too ? BEGIN; {queries}; COMMIT;